# Pass Data (String) without Storyboard

Tags: ios, string, uitableview, swift

I´ve tried the whole night finding a Solution for this, without success.
I have an TableView with multiple Cell´s, a View which pop´s in (MaryPopin) when a Cell is selected.
My Problem here is to pass the Data from the Cell to the popped in View.

Where the Data should be stored in Meldungen.swift

```
struct Meldungen {

    var meldungenBody : String = ""

}
```

My actuall State in  TableViewController.swift

```
lazy var meldungen = Meldungen()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        var Body = self.Feeds[indexPath.row]
        var BodyText = Body["body"] as String!
            self.meldungen.meldungenBody = BodyText

                  //      println(BodyText)


        let popin = ShowFeedViewController(nibName: "ShowFeedViewController", bundle:nil)
        popin.delegate = self
        popup(popin)


    }
```

Here the "BodyText" should be stored as String in Meldungen.swift
When I println() the BodyText it show´s the output I´m looking for.

Then where I need the String ShowFeedViewController.swift I´ve tried just to println()

```
lazy var meldungen = Meldungen()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println(meldungen.meldungenBody)

    }
```

Getting just "" as declared in Meldungen.swift

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Each time you have `lazy var meldungen = Meldungen()` a new struct is created with default values.  That means you have two of them in the code you posted: the one that has your updated text and a different one that you print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved =D

My TableViewController.swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        var Body = self.Feeds[indexPath.row]
        var BodyText = Body["body"] as String!

        let popin = ShowFeedViewController(nibName: "ShowFeedViewController", bundle:nil)
        popin.delegate = self
        popin.BodyPass = BodyText
        popup(popin)


    }
```

My ShowFeedViewController

```
var BodyPass: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            println(BodyPass)

        }
```

Thx to Caleb who posted a Solution but then deleted his answer ^^ idk why